# Enabling second screen

Tags: system-installation, multiple-monitors

I recently installed Ubuntu on my sleekbook 15. Well my sleekbook screen is broken and I can't see a thing. I was broadcasting a second screen in Windows through an HDMI port and it worked great. I got rid of Windows when installed Ubuntu and my screen didn't switch over, which was an after thought of course, on my part. Now I have no idea how to switch it to TV and I'm stuck without a computer. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for a function key on your laptop keyboard to switch monitors. It will usually have some sort of a little screen pic on it. On my laptop it is

```
Fn+F7
```

Run Your LiveUSB again and press whichever it is on your laptop. If you can't tell which one it is try all the fn combos (F1 through F12) until you get a display on your ext monitor. After pressing each time wait a moment for your card to redirect the output.

If this doesn't work check your PCs user manual. Sometimes special keys need some kind of drivers to work.